# Anyone know of a library that has a lot of useful CharSequences

Tags: java

It seems strange that no helper named something like CharSequences is available in the JDK when there are so many obvious utility implementations.

- repeating character
- char[] - yes i know about CharBuffer.wrap
- padding - wrap another CharSequence and pad - obviously both left and right versions
- trimming - trim a CharSequence left or right of whitespace.
- quoting - add quotes around another CharSequence.

etc.

Feel free to expand the list if you wish...

Comment: Frankly, I no longer know what you're asking for. APIs that takes `CharSequence` as input are not what you're looking for. APIs that *produce* `CharSequence` are not what you're looking for. And APIs that *implement* with different performance characteristics are also not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The API is not exactly what you describe and not all of the functons are available, but the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) class [`CharMatcher`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) provides part of it and some more niceties.

- [`CharMatcher.DIGIT.trimFrom(input)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#trimFrom%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- [`CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.trimLeadingFrom(input)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#trimLeadingFrom%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- [`CharMatcher.anyOf("aeiou").removeFrom(input)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#removeFrom%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- [`CharMatcher.inRange('a','z').matchesAllOf(input)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#matchesAllOf%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: CharMatcher matches characters i want real concrete CharSequences. I could build a String eventually but then that defeats the purpose of using CharSequence to begin w/.

Comment: @mP: I don't see it as defeating the purpose of a `CharSequence`. Therefore you probably have a different idea of what the purpose is. What do *you* think the purpose of `CharSequence` is?

Comment: A CharSequence is a sequence of characters, A CharMatcher matches a character using some in built predicate. One is equivalent to a char[] and the other boolean - really dont see how they are even closely equivalent.

Comment: Uhm ... every `input` in my samples can be any `CharSequence` and the return value of every one of my methods is another `CharSequence` (specifically a `String`). The `CharMatcher` is just a way of defining a common set of characters on which to operate with a common operation.

Answer (score 0):

Check StringUtils in the apache commons lang library
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: That's the obvious answer, but there is not a single `CharSequence` method in this class.

Comment: & @Sean: Q says CharSequence not String. Everyone knows about StringUtils :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither Guava nor Apache Commons / Lang (nor the JRE library itself) has functionality like this based on the `CharSequence` interface.

One could imagine Guava having a `CharSequences` class for methods like this, but unfortunately several issues that requested for methods like this have already been rejected.

Comment: At a guess its probably because there is no guarantee that a CharSequence is immutable because its an interface :(

Comment: @mP: best example: [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Of course anyone who needs an immutable CharSequence needs to do a toString() if it accepts a CharSequence.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library that kind-of takes the other approach: It provides implemntations of `CharSequence` that are optimized for some specific use cases: [Ropes for Java](http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/)

If you use [`Rope`](http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/doc/org/ahmadsoft/ropes/Rope.html)s in your code, you can tweak the specific implementations to be used to speed up regular operations (concatenation, removing sub-`CharSequence`es, ...).

Comment: I think i ve seen Ropes before - it holds sequences of chars in blocks behind a fascade making for a more efficient handling of very long "sequences". However Rope is a not a CharSequence and would require toStringing to be of use when calling other stuff.

Comment: @mP: a Rope **is** a `CharSequence`. Check the link in my answer.

Comment: i didnt notice it implemented CharSequence asthe API seemed quite different. Except for performance reasons it offers basically the same functionality as String/StringBuilder. I was originally thinking of something that transforms one CharSequence into another - look at the examples in the q.

Comment: You can use the Ropes to implement them: for example, for repeating the character `'x'` 100 times, produce a `new RepeatedCharacterSequence('x', 100)`. You can *easily* (and efficiently) produce padded `CharSequence` objects using a `ConcatenationRope` (same goes for quoting).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that lots of the jdk api methods that *could* take CharSequence only take Strings.  therefore, the usefulness of CharSequence is limited (and many of the impls that do take CharSequences just call `toString()` anyway, negating much of the benefit).

that said, it is certainly a useful idea.  could use the repeating version right now.

Comment: The repeater was simplistic examplebut yeh its amazing given the number of utilities in Collections but there is no equivalent for CharSequences.